# Creating .nomedia files with Storage Access Framework / SD

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm using SAF so that users can store videos on their external SD cards or even USB drives with my camera app. I don't want them to appear in the gallery though, so I need to create a .nomedia file.

I'm using this code currently:

```
 mTreeUri = Uri.parse(treeUri);
        mPickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, mTreeUri);
        if (treeUri != null) {
            final DocumentFile existingMediaFile = mPickedDir.findFile(".nomedia");
            if (existingMediaFile == null) {

                DocumentFile newFile = mPickedDir.createFile("text/plain", ".nomedia");
                if (newFile == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                OutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
                    out.write("A long time ago...".getBytes());
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Nomedia", e);
                }
```

The problem is that SAF creates a file called nomedia.txt instead of the dotfile. I played around with a few different mime types in the application/* range but then no file gets created at all. Glad for any pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

And found it. Using any kind of custom mime type like "thisis/awesome" seems to work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunatley it doesn't look like it's working anymore. Any idea on how to create a .nomedia file?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late for an answer, but I would suggest something like:

```
new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), ".nomedia").createNewFile();
```

Comment: Oops `java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

"application/octet-stream" works fine. That's the default mime type for cases when something more specific doesn't apply.

Comment: Oops `MIME type application/octet-stream cannot be inserted into content://media/external_primary/images/media; expected MIME type under image/*`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're do to cause that error, but adding a .nomedia file just requires this:  `myDocumentFile.createFile("application/octet-stream", ".nomedia")`